# How to solve the intergo-differential equation with derivative

Tags: differential-equations, integral-equations

[image][image]

I do not know how to handle the integro-term.

```
ieqn = 
 1 - 6.25*10^5*x[t] + 1.234*10^4*Integrate[x'[u]/Sqrt[t - u], {u, 0, t}] == 1.5924*x''[t];
ic = {x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 0};
sol = DSolve[{ieqn, ic}, x[t], t];
Plot[x[t] /. sol, {t, 0, 0.007}]
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is this about Wolfram Mathematica? Have you tried do find something in [integro-differential topics](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=Integro-differential)?

Comment: the value of t do not change the output of the figure or curve,and i do not know what's wrong with my code

Comment: Which version are you in? In _v11.2_  `DSolve` returns unevaluated.

Answer (score 0):

I use `"11.3.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)"`.

Copy-pasting the proposed code I receive only a slew of errors and no output (only the axes, but no graph).

Instead, writing:

```
f[u_?NumericQ] := x'[u]/Sqrt[t - u]
ieqn = 1 - 6.25 10^5 x[t] + 1.2341 10^4 Integrate[f[u], {u, 0, t}] == 1.5924 x''[t];
ic = {x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 0};
xsol = NDSolveValue[{ieqn, ic}, x, {t, 0, 0.01}] // Quiet;
Plot[xsol[t], {t, 0, 0.01}] // Quiet
```

I get:

[image]

where the two `Quiet` still hide a series of errors.

Comment: I'm afraid this solution is not reliable, because you've hidden the `x'[u]` in a blackbox function, `NDSolve` won't be able to handle it corectly.